# What would be the best possible way to disable c++ code during runtime with the least overhead introduced

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, c++17

** Very Newbie Designer here... But love to discuss and work out the best solution possible! :)

Motivation: I want to add a tracing library, which needs to be optional in a complex and high performance disruptive need-based project.

I am thinking of using std::optional to propagate its data structures.

I am not able to find the best solution to enable and disable this library such that it produces least overhead to the running system, I have some things in mind on how to achive it:

- general, bool check

```
if(library_enabled) {

//do library stuff

}
```

- null all the functions definations + ptrs and covert all non nullables ( int, double etc ) to char

```
f(library_enabled) {

ptr func(arg 1, arg 2) {}

} else

void func(null) {}
```

can we think of some better way to solve this design problem, taking performance in mind?

Comment: You may check `std::enable_if`.

Comment: When yoou mean optional, do you mean optionally load a dll ?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy optional as in std::optional parameter c++

Comment: std::optional<something> will always be at least as large as that 'something' , so no gains to be had this way.  A pointer woud probably be better suiited for the ttask.